# I'm using a list and OnItemClickListener but when I click the item,it doesn't go anywhere

Tags: java, android, genymotion

This is my xml code,I hope it helps it's a relative layout as you can see..

```
<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="350dp"
    android:id="@+id/listView2"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Delete"
    android:id="@+id/deletebutton12"
    android:layout_above="@+id/listView2"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

Comment: onClick app stop or nothing happen?

Comment: Have you set your `listview`'s `onItemClickListener` to ur `listListener`?

Comment: debug your code and see really onItemClick() method run

Comment: @MHP it didn't run.what could be the problem??

Answer (score 1):

Use `getItemAtPosition()`:

```
AdapterView.OnItemClickListener listListener = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                            long arg3) {

        ApartmentPhoto item = (ApartmentPhoto) arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2);

        Intent intent = new Intent(ViewYourApartments.this,
                MainActivityTest.class);
        intent.putExtra("ID",String.valueOf(item.id));
        startActivity(intent);

    }
};
```

If it doesn't go anywhere, check if `ViewYourApartments.this` is the activity on which you are running the listener and `MainActivityTest.class` is the destination.

**UPDATE**

Are you sure that you are invoking the listener on the `ListView`?

Something like that:

```
ListView lv = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView);
lv.setOnItemClickListener(listListener);
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72531/discussion-on-answer-by-fondesa-im-using-a-list-and-onitemclicklistener-but-whe).